# CSS transition of a div does not animate

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

When I click a div, I want a second div to expand/collapse. That is done using JS, HTML, and CSS. Now I want the CSS transition to animate.

Right now all I get is a jumping expansion and either a scroll (Edge) or a jump after a wait (Chrome, Opera, Firefox).

I've tried to set height to 1px instead of 0px, but that doesn't change anything.

```js
function growDiv(id) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(id);
  if (ele.style.height == '100%') {
    ele.style.height = '0px';
  } else {
    ele.style.height = '100%';
  }
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.secondary {
  -webkit-transition: height .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .5s ease;
  -o-transition: height .5s ease;
  transition: height .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" onclick="growDiv('expandable')">
  Expand
</div>
<div class="secondary" id="expandable" onclick="growDiv('expandable')">
  number1,
  <br>number2,
  <br>number3,
  <br>number4.
</div>
```

Codepen behaves as I know the full site does, so for good measure; here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezJQjM

Comment: Using PX instead of % worked on your codepen (in the JS function)

Comment: You can't animate between px and %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you willing to use jQuery? It offers some cool animation possibilities, and may accomplish what you are trying to do. This is just a possible alternative to your approach.

Check out my fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mo28z1t/11/

```
<div class="main" id="clicker">
  Expand
</div>
<div class="secondary" id="expandable">
  number1, <br> number2, <br> number3, <br> number4.
</div>

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {

$(".secondary").hide();

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#clicker").click(function () {
            $(".secondary").toggle("slow");
        });

    });   

});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried to stay away from JQuery to reduce page size. It might just be 84 kB, but if I could avoid it I would prefer that -- especially since the entire rest of my project right now spans just 34 kB. Also, I don't understand the downvote; I never specifically asked for a solution devoid of JQuery, just like I didn't ask for a JQuery solution. I'll try you solution, thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. I just had to include JQuery in the head instead of, as I tried, in the bottom.

Comment: Actually it introduced a new problem, at least as far as I can tell. Namely that `div.secondary` having 100 % screen width rather than 100 % parent width. I solved it using the CSS function `calc(100% - offset)` where `offset` is the padding and margins of parent divs. I can't guarantee that the problem is from this solution, only that I did not see it until after this was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

From http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/
Instead of using 100%, just "let it" get the auto value by not restraining it.

NOTE: 100px is just "any number bigger than the actual size"

```js
function growDiv(id) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(id);
  if (ele.style.maxHeight != '0vh') {
    ele.style.maxHeight = '0vh';
  } else {
    ele.style.maxHeight = "100vh";
  }
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.secondary {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" onclick="growDiv('expandable')">
  Expand
</div>
<div class="secondary" id="expandable" onclick="growDiv('expandable')" style="max-height: 0vh;">
  number1,
  <br>number2,
  <br>number3,
  <br>number4.
</div>
```

EDIT: Changed everything to VH (viewport height) so it will never grow bigger than 100% of the screen height and will adapt to the max height of any screen.
Also switched the "style="max-height: 0vh;" to the element itself instead of the class, so you could be unsetting it with ele.style if needed (otherwise you will need to set a new value to override the class.

Comment: The transition works now. But it doesn't scale well. Say I have four points in one list, but twenty in another. (Strictly speaking the implementation is not a list, but for the sake of argument..) I could of course make the function accept a max-height and tune it manually, but then there's the problem of differing screen sizes. Any suggestion for solving it programmatically?

Comment: You could change everything to "vh" (start with 0vh, then grow max-height to 100vh) so it will never be bigger than 100% of the screen size. 1vh = 1% of viewport height. Edited the answer, should work perfectly fine unless one of the "lists" is actually bigger than one screen height, of course you could actually tune this setting it to 200vh or whatever is the size of the longests of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by switching units of measure, so from pixels to percent. I would probable do it a little differently though.

```js
growDiv = function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('expanded');
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.secondary {
  transition: max-height .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.secondary.expanded {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" onclick="growDiv('expandable')">
  Expand
</div>
<div class="secondary" id="expandable" onclick="growDiv('expandable')">
  number1,
  <br>number2,
  <br>number3,
  <br>number4.
</div>
```

You'll notice the JS is a bit simpler, and it relies more on the CSS.

Comment: Beautiful solution, but lacks scale. If I add number5, number6, and number7, number6 it cut off half way and number7 is not shown. I suppose I want something else than what I'm asking for.

Comment: You can make the max-height a larger number to show more results.